# Back up of Mac and Windows on the same time machine

Tags: windows, mac, backup

We are a team of workers; Some of our members use PC (Window machine) and some use MAC (OS X); We plan to back up the both type of machines on a single time machine; Is this Possible? If yes, than how?

Answer (score 4):

Time Machine is the name of Apple's backup software built into Mac OS X. The is no Windows version of it. Time *Capsule* is the name of Apple's "Wi-Fi router with hard drive" box.

Time Capsule shares its hard drive via both the AFP protocol for Macs, and the SMB protocol for Windows.

Your Macs running Time Machine will need to be told to use it as a backup disk. After that, they will perform an initial full backup, and then automatic hourly incremental backups. When the Time Capsule's disk space fills up, the Macs will automatically thin out their old incrementals to free up space.

For Windows, you'll need to pick your own backup software solution, but anything that can back up to an SMB file server should work.